# How Can I add variables from a query string to a path of the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

**The current URL**
www.mydomain.com/?ct_keyword&ct_city=la-jolla&ct_property_type=apartments&ct_ct_status=for-rent

**New URL** .
www.mydomain.com/**valueof-ct_city**/**valueof-ct_property_type**/**valueof-ct_status**?ct_keyword&ct_city=la-jolla&ct_property_type=apartments&ct_ct_status=for-rent

Note: It should take 3 variables from the string and add it to the path

**Example of the results**
www.mydomain.com/la-jolla/apartments/for-rent/?ct_keyword&ct_city=la-jolla&ct_property_type=apartments&ct_ct_status=for-rent

And of course, the query string is changing so it should take the variables from the current query string.
The query string has more variables in it, I just want the 3 specified above added to the path.

The site is based on WordPress.

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result?  Without a code sample of what you've tried and a bad result, it's going to be very difficult to help.

Comment: have any code sample??? Check This Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338047/10771500 or with php (Server Side): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366077/10771500

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Improve formatting and english

Answer (score -1):

Use the ampersand & to glue variables together:

$url = "http://domainname/main.php?email=$email_address&event_id=$event_id";